# Vim isn't loading syntax

Tags: vim, syntax

I had an unrelated problem with vim a while back, that I thought deleting all vim files would help. It did not, but now I have a new problem. Whenever I try to put syntax on, it says:

```
Error detected while processing /home/jonah/.vimrc:
line   16:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
```

I've tried reinstalling fully, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Edit your question and paste your .vimrc where it  "It turns syntax highlighting on with 'syntax on'. –  Theodcyning 4 mins ago "

Comment: It turns syntax highlighting on with 'syntax on'.

Comment: @Theodcyning What is the exact code?

Comment: @admdrew The entire line is just 'syntax on'.

Comment: What is the content of /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim ?

Comment: @Simson /usr/share/vim isn't in existence, I deleted it with all the other files I deleted when trying to fix the other problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have a broken Vim installation with missing runtime files. The file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim` needs to be there. **You should never modify / remove system runtime files in /usr/share/vim yourself!** Use your distribution's package manager (you didn't tell which Linux disto you're using) to completely reinstall Vim, and ensure that the file is there.

Comment: I'm using synaptic, how do I do this? Both completely removing and reinstalling have not worked.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the runtime is in the `vim-runtime` package, not in `vim` / `vim-gnome`. Try reinstalling that.